# Unable to do the add, delete nodes in DOM XML document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Actually i am working on the XML DOM parser for the bellow xml string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema version="1.0">
  <itemGroups>
    <itemGroup id="itemGroup1">
      <items>
        <item id="One" />
        <item id="Two" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
      </items>
    </itemGroup>
    <itemGroup id="itemGroup2">
      <items>
        <item id="One" />
        <item id="Two" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
        <item id="item1" />
      </items>
    </itemGroup>
  </itemGroups> 
</schema>
```

Here from each itemGroup i need to remove the items which has the id like 'item'. Please help me to do this thing by using Document object only.

This is the Code we are using to remove the element but getting null pointer exception

```
public static Document removeElement(Document doc, String idValue,
            String groupNode, String itemNode) {
        NodeList itemGroupList = doc.getElementsByTagName(groupNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemGroupList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element node = (Element) itemGroupList.item(i);
            if (node.getAttribute("id").equals(idValue)) {
                NodeList itemlist = node.getElementsByTagName(itemNode);
                for (int j = 0; j < itemlist.getLength(); j++) {
                    Element nodenewitm = (Element) itemlist.item(j);
                    NodeList nodeListRemove = nodenewitm.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    if(nodenewitm != null) {
                        NodeList itemsList = nodenewitm.getChildNodes();
                        if(itemsList != null) {
                            for (int counter = 0; counter < itemsList.getLength(); counter++) {
                                Element item = (Element) itemlist.item(counter);
                                if(item.getAttribute("id").indexOf("ATTR_") > 0) {
                                    nodenewitm.removeChild(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

We are just calling removeElement(document, "itemGroup1", "itemGroup", "items");

I appreciate if i get help on this soon.

Thanks
Ramesh Reddy

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath instead. You can construct the expression according to your needs.

```
void removeElement(Document doc)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.evaluate(
            "//items/item[starts-with(@id, 'item')]", doc,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
        nl.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(nl.item(i));
    }
}
```